# Custom AngularJS directive with xeditable: doesn't work first time, but works afterward

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-xeditable

Building an AngularJS application, I'm using *xeditable* to allow the user to edit a table, row per row (as described here: [xeditable](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-row)).

The *Edit*, *Remove* and *Cancel* button logic being a bit cumbersome to implement in each table, I created a custom directive: `sen-edit-row`.

The logic of the buttons in the custom directive works well... except in one case.

When the user clicks [Add], a row is added (just like in *xeditable*'s example), and the new row is immediately editable. Or it should!

The **very first time**, the row is not editable. The input fields are not created by *xeditable*. The buttons of my own directive still work.

But the most bizarre thing is: the **2nd time** the user clicks [Add], it just works. And then it keeps working!

(this is driving me nuts)

#### In the HTML, the directive is called this way:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="access in denyAccessTable">
      <td class="col-md-4"><div editable-text="access.user" e-form="rowForm">{{ access.user }}</div></td>
      <td class="col-md-4"><div editable-text="access.host" e-form="rowForm">{{ access.host }}</div></td>
      <td class="col-md-2"><div editable-text="access.mode" e-form="rowForm">{{ access.mode }}</div></td>
      <td class="col-md-2"><div sen-edit-row save="saveDenyAccess()" remove="removeDenyAccess($index)" shown="access == newDenyAccess"></div></td>
    </tr>
```

#### In the JS, the directive is defined as:

```
angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]).directive("senEditRow", [function() {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    templateUrl: "sen-edit-row.html",
    scope: {
        save: "&",
        remove: "&",
        shown: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    }
}
}])
```

#### And the template of the directive:

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap">
    <form class="form-inline" editable-form name="rowForm" onaftersave="save()" ng-show="rowForm.$visible" shown="shown">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="rowForm.$waiting">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" ng-disabled="rowForm.$waiting" ng-click="shown ? remove() : rowForm.$cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Buttons to edit and remove -->
    <div ng-hide="rowForm.$visible">
        <a href="" ng-click="rowForm.$show()" ng-hide="showDeleteButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span>Edit</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="showDeleteButton = true" ng-hide="showDeleteButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 5px;"></span>Remove</a>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove()" ng-show="showDeleteButton">Remove</button>
        <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="showDeleteButton = false" ng-show="showDeleteButton">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also created a [Plunker that shows evidence of this behavior](https://embed.plnkr.co/TKsa86FfA8ahb90IQbCu/).

**Question: How do I make my directive and *xeditable* work consistently, including the first time, and activate immediately when a row is added to the table?**

Thank you!